# Evaluate forecasting quality

Tags: probability, statistics

A statistical model calculate the probability that some independent event occurs. These events either occur or not (binary outcome).

I am looking to evaluate the quality of my forecasting. I looked into things like [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score), or [log score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Logarithmic_scoring_rule).

- How can I evaluate the quality of the forecast?
- How can I calculate a confidence interval for the quality of the forecast (in other words, how do I know how many observations are necessary before I can evaluate reliably the quality of my forecast)?

Comment: I added Wikipedia references to your question. If you have other sources, it would be a good idea to include them in your question.

Comment: what is then wrong with using those methods you mentioned?

Comment: I think people with more experience in the field might have better ideas, or at least pointers on how to use these indicators well. Also I do not know how to calculate the confidence interval (say I have a bad Brier score, do I just need to collect more data, or do I need to work again on my model?)